# Convert JSONArray to List<HashMap<String,Object>> in java without GSON

Tags: java, json, list, java-8, hashmap

I have a `JSONArray` from `net.minidev.json` which I want to convert to `List<HashMap<String,Object>>`.

There are many answers for converting the `JSONArray` using `Gson`.

However, I cannot add `Gson` as a dependency to my `pom.xml`, so I am looking for a way to achieve it with **Java-8** features.

My `JSONArray` is something like this: It comprises **multiple hierarchies**.

```
[
  {
    "data": {
      "name": "idris"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "processStandardDeduction": 69394,
        "cropId": 1,
        "data": null,
        "expectedQuantityPerAcre": 1220,
        "name": "Red Tomato 1 quality",
        "id": 1003,
        "autoArchivePlotDays": 59902
      },
      {
        "processStandardDeduction": 69394,
        "cropId": 1,
        "autoArchivePlotDays": 59902
      },
      {
        "processStandardDeduction": 69394,
        "cropId": 1,
        "autoArchivePlotDays": 59902
      }
    ],
    "name": "Red Tomato",
    "id": 1002
  },
  {
    "data": null,
    "name": "Red Tomato 1 quality",
    "id": 1003,
    "processStandardDeduction": 69394,
    "cropId": 1,
    "expectedQuantityPerAcre": 1220,
    "cropName": "Tomato",
    "autoArchivePlotDays": 59902
  },
  {
    "data": null,
    "name": "Red Tomato 3 quality",
    "id": 1001,
    "processStandardDeduction": 69394,
    "autoArchivePlotDays": 59902
  },
  {
    "processStandardDeduction": 69394,
    "cropId": 1,
    "data": null,
    "id": 1004,
    "autoArchivePlotDays": 59902
  }
]
```

I would like to achieve same structure in List>

I tried looping each element of the JSONArray by converting it to each `HashMap<String,Object>` and then adding it to the `List<HashMap<String,Object>>`.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<HashMap<String, Object>> cropDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object eachCropJson : cropDetails) { //cropDetails is the JSONArray

            HashMap<String, Object> eachCropMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) mapper.convertValue(eachCropJson,
                    HashMap.class);
            cropDetailsList.add(eachCropMap);
        }
return cropDetailsList;
```

I would like to try a better approach using ***Java-8 features*** without using a forEach. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just using `map` and collecting should work `cropDetails.stream().map(eachCropMap -> (Map<String, Object>) mapper.convertValue(eachCropJson, HashMap.class)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get this `JSON` as `String` then you can use `ObjectMapper.readValue` method

```
readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef)
```

**Code**

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> cropDetailsList = mapper.readValue(jsonString,
                                   new TypeReference<List<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){});
```

In the same way if you want to iterate `JSONArray`

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> cropDetailsList = cropDetails.stream()
            .map(eachCropJson->(HashMap<String, Object>) mapper.convertValue(eachCropJson, HashMap.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wouldn't conversion of a JSONArray to a String become a costly operation? If it is not, then I shall use this method.
Since I am already using a mapper to convert each Object of JSONArray to a HashMap, I am not sure which approach is better in terms of performance.

Comment: I don't think it is a costly operation, `toString()` should work for that @MohammedIdris, but i gave you the second approach also

Comment: still you can avoid this type casting `(HashMap<String, Object>)` do some google search @MohammedIdris

Comment: The first approach seems to work as expected.

 However, the `StreamSupport.stream` says `the method stream(Spliterator<T>, boolean) is  not applicable for the arguments (JSONArray, boolean)`. 
Do I use cast `(Spliterator<JSONObject>)` or `(Spliterator<HashMap<String,Object>>)`?

Also, Is Type Casting a bad idea? @Deadpool

Comment: can you tell me `JSONArray` is from which library ?, i mean better to avoid explicit type casting as much as possible  @MohammedIdris

Comment: The JSONArray is from `net.minidev.json.JSONArray` library.

Comment: It works as expected with the updated answer. Thanks @Deadpool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196855/discussion-between-mohammed-idris-and-deadpool).

Answer (score 2):

Using stream this can be done

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> output = cropDetails.toList().stream().map(m -> ((HashMap<String, Object>) m)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `cropDetails` is a `JSONArray`. `toList()` function is undefined for type `JSONArray`. @SUMIT NAVIN

Comment: Using stream on `cropDetails JSONArray` gave me the expected result.